# A 'Z' after the date in the 'date asked' title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've been browsing Stack Overflow questions and suddenly noticed:

[image: There is a 'Z' after every date]

As you might see, there is a 'Z' after the date if you hover over the 'asked ... seconds ago' text in a post, I took this as an example. It might not really be a 'bug' but it sure is a visual error, maybe somebody forgot to remove it?

If you hover over my 'date asked', the title will also add a 'Z' at the end. This bothers me a lot for no apparent reason.

Comment: It shouldn't bother you, it's there intentionally and it won't be going away.

Comment: "..who let the Z out?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not a bug, but ISO 8601 date notation.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".